# Cross-domain scripting ColdFusion issue

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, cross-domain, extjs4.1

I have a silly question but I am a newbie. I am trying to make a cross-domain request (via ajax) using extjs4 library. As server side language I am using ColdFusion. The whole code that I have written so far is working on same domain. I need to separate static files (javascript, css, and html) placing them on Apache server and the dynamic content (cfm, CFC) placing them over Tomcat (openbd). So the front end scripts (on Apache->javascript mainly) making requests on Tomcat in order to fetch content. This definitely is cross-domain requests.

**A code block that I am using in order to pull data (CFC) is:**

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
<cfset setEncoding("URL", "utf-8")>

    <cffunction name="getContent" access="remote" returnFormat="JSON" output="false" >  
        <cfargument name="start" default="0"/>    
        <cfargument name="limit" default="1000"/>
        <cfargument name="id" default="0" required="false" type="numeric">
        <cfargument name="model" default="" required="false" type="any">

        <cfset var arrNomoi = ArrayNew(1)>
        <cfset var stcReturn = "">

        <!--- When going back to base state, ExtJS will make the function call with start set to 0. If this is the case
        we set it to 1 --->
        <cfset Arguments.start = Arguments.start + 1>


        <cfif arguments.model EQ 'n_2664_1998'>

            <cfquery name="getNomoi" datasource="ktimatologio">
                SELECT CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS id, id AS 'id1', CONCAT_WS(' ',title,fek,date) AS 'title', description, body, model
                FROM n_2664_1998
                WHERE id = #arguments.id#
                ORDER BY id ASC
            </cfquery>

        <cfelseif arguments.model EQ 'n_2308_1995'>

            <cfquery name="getNomoi" datasource="ktimatologio">
                SELECT CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS id, id AS 'id1', CONCAT_WS(' ',title,fek,date) AS 'title', description, body, model
                FROM n_2308_1995
                WHERE id = #arguments.id#
                ORDER BY id ASC
            </cfquery>

        <cfelseif arguments.model EQ 'n_3889_2010'> 

            <cfquery name="getNomoi" datasource="ktimatologio">
                SELECT CONCAT_WS('_',id,model) AS id, id AS 'id1', CONCAT_WS(' ',title,fek,date) AS 'title', description, body, model
                FROM n_3889_2010
                WHERE id = #arguments.id#
                ORDER BY id ASC
            </cfquery>  

        </cfif>

        <cfset arrNomoi = convertQueryToExtJS(getNomoi,Arguments.start,Arguments.limit)>

        <cfset stcReturn = {"data"=arrNomoi,dataset=#getNomoi.RecordCount#}>

        <cfreturn stcReturn>

    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="convertQueryToExtJS" access="public" hint="Convert Query to JSON usable by ExtJS Grid" returntype="array">
        <cfargument name="qryData" type="query" required="true" hint="Query to convert">
        <cfargument name="intStart" type="numeric" required="true" hint="Start of Result Set">
        <cfargument name="intLimit" type="numeric" required="true" hint="How many records to return">

        <!--- For the Array --->    
        <cfset var i = 1>        
        <cfset var end = ((Arguments.intStart) + arguments.intLimit)-1>
        <cfset var arrNomoi = ArrayNew(1)>

        <cfloop query="qryData" startrow="#Arguments.intStart#" endrow="#end#">        
            <cfset stcNomoi = StructNew()>
            <cfset stcNomoi['id'] = #qryData.id#>
            <cfset stcNomoi['id1'] = #qryData.id1#>
            <cfset stcNomoi['title'] = #qryData.title#>
            <!---<cfset stcNomoi['fek'] = #qryData.fek#>
            <cfset stcNomoi['date'] = #qryData.date#>--->
            <cfset stcNomoi['description'] = #qryData.description#>
            <cfset stcNomoi['body'] = #qryData.body#>
            <cfset stcNomoi['model'] = #qryData.model#>
            <cfset arrNomoi[i] = stcNomoi>
            <cfset i = i + 1>            
        </cfloop>


        <cfreturn arrNomoi>

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

The question is: how do I wrap the above function into a variable (named “callback”) and post it on client?

**I have seen a similar code block on PHP but I don’t understand. Below is the PHP code block:**

```
<?php
$callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];
// Create the output object.
$output = array('id' => 1, 'url' => 'loianegroner.com');
//start output
if ($callback) {
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
echo $callback . '([' . json_encode($output) . ']);';
} else {
header('Content-Type: application/x-json');
echo json_encode($output);
} 
?>
```

With respect,

Tom

Greece

Comment: Would this help? It is an example of how to build a JSON/P service in ColdFusion - http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2009/3/11/Writing-a-JSONP-service-in-ColdFusion

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it is a great honor a response by you. Now the problem, I have already revied your example but I had no luck. I don't know what it is going wrong. I trying to develop locally. So, I have on the same machine Apache server on port 80 and Tomcat on port 8090. From Tomcat I am serving dynamic cfc's mainly (using openbd) and from Apache I am serving static (Extjs library). I am not pri

Comment: I am not proxing Tomcat to Apache. I have just seperated my scripts to static (putting them on Apache) and dynamic (putting them on Tomcat)

Comment: I'd need more details on why it isn't working. You also want to ensure that 'simple' requests of the CFC work remotely. So if your CFC is at localhost:8090/something.cfc you can open your browser to http://localhost:8090/something.cfc?method=getcontent. It should output the data.

Comment: When I point my browser to the cfc yes it is giving me output. But when I calling them from apache it is giving me nothing. I think it is a SOP related problem. I don't know how to tackle it. Is there a way to inject script tags at cfc's output. I am afraid that I am using your example in wrong fashion. The output that cfc is giving looks like: callback('the_json_output'). I think it is wrong. The cfc output needs headers script tags or I don't know what. Isn't it?

Comment: You say when you call it from Apache you get nothing. Are you confirming this in your browser with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: Thank Mr.Camden. The jsonp example that you provided yesterday was 100% useful. As originally thought the mistake was from my side. I am very new in programming (especially in ExtJs library). Thank you again. With respect, Tom, Greece

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two files:

The index.cfm is the handler where you submit an AJAX request to and it will return a JSON result

http://websvn.openbd.org/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=OpenBD&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fwebapp%2Fmanual%2Fapi%2Findex.cfm

The index.cfm interacts with this CFC to fetch the information and return the result.

http://websvn.openbd.org/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=OpenBD&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fwebapp%2Fmanual%2Fapi%2Findex.cfc

When I was writing this API wrapper I had issues with returnFormat=JSON